# how to deal with many-to-many relationship in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-populate, auto-populate

it is easy to deal with 1-1(via refs) or 1-N(via populate virtuals) relations in MongoDB
but how to deal with N-M relations?
suppose I have 2 entities teacher and classroom
many teachers can access many classrooms
many classrooms can be accessed by many teachers

```
teacher.schema
{
  name:String;
  //classrooms:Array;
}
```

```
classrooms.schema
{
  name:String;
  //teachers:Array
}
```

is there a **direct way**(similar like populate virtuals) to keep this N-M relations so that when one teacher removed, then teachers in classroom can automatically be changed too?
should I use a third 'bridge' schema like `TeacherToClassroom` to record their relations?

i am thinking of some thing like this, like a `computed value`

```
teacher.schema
{
  name:String;
  classrooms:(row)=>{
    return db.classrooms.find({_id:{$elemMatch:row._id }})
  }
}
```

```
classrooms.schema
{
  name:String;
  teachers:{Type:ObjectId[]}
}
```

so that i just manage the teacher ids in classrooms, then the classroom property in teach schema will auto computed

Comment: I see you edited most of your post. Does my answer still provide a solution for you?

Comment: thx but sorry bro. the info in your anwser  is what i already know. but that's not help. i commented u and explained what i am thinking and looking for

Answer (score 1):

The literature describes a few methods on how to implement a m-n relationship in Mongodb.

The first method is by two-way embedding. Looking at an example using books and director of movies:

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "Peter Griffin",
  books: [1, 2]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  name: "Luke Skywalker",
  books: [2]
}

{
  _id: 1,
  title: "War of the oceans",
  categories: ["drama"],
  authors: [1, 2]
}
{
  _id: 2,
  title: "Into the loop",
  categories: ["scifi"],
  authors: [1]
}
```

The second option is to use one-way embedding. This means you only embed one of the documents into the other. Like so (movie with a genre):

```
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "drama"
}

{
  _id: 1,
  title: "War of the oceans",
  categories: [1],
  authors: [1, 2]
}
```

When the data you are embedding becomes larger you could use something like the bucketing pattern to split it up: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern

As you can see in the above example by embedding the documents you still only need to modify the data in one location. You do not need any intermediate tables to do that.

In some cases you might even be able to omit an entire document when it has no meaning as a stand-alone object: [Absorbing N in a M:N relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970185/absorbing-n-in-a-mn-relationship)

Comment: i cared about consistency about 2 entities , i want that when i update one side,  another side auto updated too. so i use refs and populate virtuals. later i consider about M:N relations,i stucked

Comment: @KentWood If you look at the code in my example you will see there is no need to update two sides of the relationship as all you should embed is a reference (the unique identifier) to the other document. This means there can never be consistency issues. It looks to me like you think the full document should be embedded and that is incorrect. It would unnecessarily duplicate information. By doing that you are also limiting yourself as there would be no good method (must be done programmatically) of keeping the information up-to-date on both sides.

Comment: nah, i don't wanna full document embeded.On the contrary, i have experiences about RDBMS usage, so i prefer to use refs to link entities, just like adding foreign keys in mysql. yes, i am seeking a 'direct solution' which can be defined in Schema,maybe this is no such things, maybe i have to achieve that in a programmatically way